# Unable to install phpMyAdmin on Redhat 6. Missing librecode.so.0

Tags: redhat

I'm attempting to install phpmyadmin on a Redhat 6 box using Remi.

```
$ sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

It fails because of a dependency issue with librecode.so.0.  Any advice?

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.2.10-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-recode for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-phpseclib-crypt-aes for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mcrypt for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-gmp for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-gmp.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.6.2-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-4.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-phpseclib-crypt-aes.noarch 0:0.3.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pear(phpseclib.sourceforge.net/Crypt_Rijndael) >= 0.3.0 for package: php-phpseclib-crypt-aes-0.3.8-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-channel(phpseclib.sourceforge.net) for package: php-phpseclib-crypt-aes-0.3.8-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-recode.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librecode.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-recode-5.6.2-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.0.095-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.0.095-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtidy-0.99.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-tidy-5.6.2-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package libtidy.x86_64 0:0.99.0-19.20070615.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-channel-phpseclib.noarch 0:1.3-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-phpseclib-crypt-rijndael.noarch 0:0.3.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pear(phpseclib.sourceforge.net/Crypt_Base) for package: php-phpseclib-crypt-rijndael-0.3.8-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-recode.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librecode.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-recode-5.6.2-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-phpseclib-crypt-base.noarch 0:0.3.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-recode.x86_64 0:5.6.2-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librecode.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-recode-5.6.2-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-recode-5.6.2-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: librecode.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Is your RHEL subscription lapsed? Are you using Satellite?

Comment: The subscription is current and I'm using RHN Classic.

Comment: Well then. `recode` is certainly available in the repositories. Did you remember to enable the optional channel?

Comment: It looks like I don't have the optional channel enabled.

Using the instructions on this page: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/1/html/Client_Tools_Installation_Guide/Installing_Using_the_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_Optional_Channel.html

I'm trying to issue this command:

sudo rhn-channel --add --channel rhel-[architecture]-[operating_system]-optional-6.

I'm trying to add the optional channel but it looks like I'll need my server administrator's redhat credentials.  I will get back to you once I get this done.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing dependency `librecode.so.0` is provided by the `recode` package.

It appears that this missing package is in the RHEL optional channel. Try [enabling this channel](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/70019).

It's very often necessary to use this channel when adding packages from third party repositories.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  This worked.

I followed the instructions here.  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/1/html/Client_Tools_Installation_Guide/Installing_Using_the_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_Optional_Channel.html